# In Lion, if I keep pressing a key, why doesn't it repeat?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I don't know if there are any settings to toggle, but I figured out that if I keep pressing a button on my keyboard it doesn't repeat it and displays only one character! Can this be fixed to go back to the previous repeating behavior?

Comment: oddly `e`, `u`, `o`, `a`, `s`, `ö`, `ä`, `'`, `<`, `z`, `,`, `.`, `-`, `§`, `+`, `⎵`, `⌫`, `↩` + arrow & control keys aren't affected; or if any key is pressed together with any control key. (I have [Finnish](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/KB_Finnish_Multilingual.svg) Apple Wireless Keyboard)

Comment: I think that Kreker means that in Lion, when you hold down a key that has alternate values (such as an "e" with and accent, a new menu will appear above the letter allowing you to choose the modified character. I agree with Kreker, it seems silly then for the System Prefs keyboard pane to have key repeat settings when they don't apply. It seems like there should be a choice between the "context" menu and key repeat or a way to make them work together. I verified this behavior in Word, Excel and TextEdit. Seems like maybe a Lion oversight or something in need of UI enhancement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a new "feature" that Apple introduced in Lion.  To disable no key repeat, enter

`defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

in Terminal, and then restart your computer.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/message/15678809

Comment: ok thanks! But why I don't see the new context menu that was implemented in Lion? I don't know either why apple leave the "repeat time" in the system keyboard preferences

Comment: sorry, i can't understand what you mean by 'new context menu.'  could you possibly describe this further?  for the 'repeat time,' you can go into system prefs -> keyboard -> and it defaults to the keyboard shortcuts tab.  go to the keyboard tab and you'll see more options