# How to disable special character selection popup when a key is held down

Tags: macos, keyboard

There was [a fix that worked with Lion in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46361/keyboard-no-longer-repeats-keys-when-held-down)

`defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

but that no longer seems to work in Mavericks.

Has anyone figured out how to turn off the special character insertion popup that appears when you hold a key down in Mavericks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command still works in Mojave, High Sierra and Mavericks — don't forget to reboot or logout/login after running the command.