# How to have character accent menu _and_ key repeat

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization

So it seems you have an either/or choice for the [character accent menu or normal press-and-hold for key repeat behaviour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46361/keyboard-no-longer-repeats-keys-when-held-down).

Surely it's possible to have press and hold bring up the Character Picker accent menu, then - after a set delay - start repeating? Is there any way to enable this behaviour?

Comment: show us an example of what you trying to achieve! repeat what, the special character?

Comment: I think he means: he has it set so he can do à and á when he holds down the *a* key, but sometimes he just wants to do aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa by holding down the *a* key.

Comment: @Buscar웃 - e.g. Simply hold down 'a', up pops Character Picker then, if nothing picked within _x_ seconds, 'a' repeats according to normal settings producing 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I think I finally understood what you want, and that is not possible.

Holding a key will bring up that character accents.

But you do not want to pick one you only want to have the pressed key repeat.

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

So to do that you need following command in Terminal to enable it.

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Since the keyboard is initialized during the boot cycle, you need to restart for it to take effect.

To set it back just use `True` at the end instead of false.

Unfortunately that will disable the "Accents" pop up since those 2 functions are conflicting.

Writing a Script that switches the function for the press and hold is useless since you would need to restart anyway.

Comment: @TomGewecke I am also aware that having both is not possible, since there is only one trigger (press and hold).

Comment: No. As I said: Simply hold down 'a', up pops Character Picker then, **if nothing picked within x seconds**, 'a' repeats according to normal settings producing 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'...

The question is how to have **both**.

Comment: I know, I got that, but it does not exist, there is a setting to delay the start of repeat, but I can not find a set up where the accent pop comes on first then after time set it changes in to repeat.

Comment: Hence my question...

Comment: And the answer is, it does not exist, not possible, nada..etc...

Comment: a) Are you sure? If so, how could it be done. There are tons of more complex hacks available to fix simple issues with OS X.
b) Saying it's not possible is just as nonsensical as it sounds.

Comment: Good luck then in find the answer.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but you can start the accent by pressing `Option - <accented sound>` before typing the accented character. For example, I can type `Option - E` followed by E to type é, or maybe ó. This is how I enable key repeat and maintain the option to type accented characters. Hope it helps!